# Replacing/Overriding Java "native" Classes?

Tags: java, overriding, bigdecimal

I'm working with `BigDecimal`s and I have the requirement that a division by 0 should not result in an `ArithmeticException`, but in returning 0 instead (weird business math).

This is a rather new requirement and we already have quite a bit of code, which uses `BigDecimal`s in a lot of places. I don't want to go through all these places and implement zero checks. This also would not help me with 3rd party libraries, which might internally use `BigDecimal`s and will throw an `ArithmeticException`instead.

I'd also like to set a default precision/scale and change the `compareTo` method to able to ignore small rounding errors.

Because of all these global changes which would create a lot of "boilerplate" code, I came up with the idea to change the implementation of `BigDecimal`. I've already done this before for other 3rd party classes to fix certain bugs myself.

I replaced those classes by creating a class with the same name in the same package like the 3rd party class, and because the external jar files will be loaded after my own classes, I was able to replace them.

But creating a `java.math.BigDecimal` didn't help me, because it seems that the "native" Java classes are loaded even before my own classes.

Let's assume that I really want every single `BigDecimal` in my application to work a bit different, how would I be able to replace the "official" `BigDecimal`? Am I allowed to do that, and could there be some other, technical problems I didn't think of now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your classes in the ["bootstrap" classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#bootclass) if you want to override builtin classes.  as to the wisdom of actually doing this (i.e. your changes will affect the *entire* jvm)...

Comment: This brings me 1 step closer, but it seems like I would have to set this path for *all* java classes and provide a complete new set of the runtime and cannot just replace a single class. I was thinking about manipulating the classloader anyhow...

Comment: @noone - why do you need to provide an entire runtime?  you just need to put your class in the bootclasspath in front of the rest of the runtime (i.e. `-Xbootclasspath/p`).

Comment: Didn't work out for me, because it's a non-standard option and my JVM doesn't support it.

Comment: @noone - and which jvm is that?

Answer (score 2):

`BigDecimal` is not final, so you could definitely extend it yourself, and change its behaviour (especially by overriding the divideXXX() methods).

You won't have to change the parameters etc., but remember to change the type of actually used objects! So you will use "your" methods.

As to `compareTo()` etc. you also won't have any problems - `BigDecimal` itself implements `Comparable` interface and has its own `compareTo()`.

Comment: You misunderstood my question a bit. I know that I can extend it, but I wanted to avoid that if I can. And the default `compareTo` method might exist, but I want it to ignore a small difference. 0 = 0.0001 for example.

Comment: @noone I don't get why would you want to *avoid* (?) it. What is the reason, why not? If I misunderstood your question, then please explain this a bit more, because what you have now is the solution to your problem, which you refuse to use, because of... I don't really know why.

Comment: Because we have a lot of code which already uses BigDecimal, I'd have to replace all that with CustomBigDecimal, which is more work and new developers/maintainers of the code might forget to use the custom one and introduce "bugs", when using the standard one. It also won't effect 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @noone OK, so how do you plan to magically change it, without changing the type? Obviously you have to change it, did you read my answer? You won't change any method declarations, just objects used in runtime. `YourNewBigDecimal` will also be a `BigDecimal`, according to IS-A relation.